# Factory Girl Using Multiple Override properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have a simple factory currently defined as:

```
factory :tm_event do
    ...
    category "MyString"
    category_id { Random.rand(1..2147483647) }
    ...
end
```

I attempting to create a `TmEvent` object with the following:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:tm_event, category: 'rock', category_id: '12')
```

When this is run both category and category_id are set to `nil` within the resultant object.

If I run with either category or category_id set individually then both instances are set with the corresponding property overridden. When I create an event directly `TmEvent.create(category: 'rock', category_id:'12')` then both attributes are populated.

Is my syntax correct? 
Where should I look for a solution?

Comment: What is `tm_event`? What is `category`? Can you please share this model. I think what you're trying to do is to create a category along with the `tm_event`.

Comment: @RyanBigg tm_event is an ActiveRecord Model object with category is a string and category_id is an integer. Changing the id string to an integer, in the create method makes no difference either.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax seems right. I just tried out the same in my console. It updates both the attributes.

```
2.1.2 :010 >   FactoryGirl.build(:user)
 => #<User id: nil, email: "example@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$WnXKcpKZt0kkkXyRRe/QP.NS7mIaFcgFzCpZhW0hzEO...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, god: nil, name: "Test User 123", sash_id: nil, level: 0, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2014-09-12 11:58:28", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil>
2.1.2 :011 > FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: '123', sign_in_count: 2)
 => #<User id: nil, email: "123", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$JIjhQp40Lz/2fCskW63lzOHHxV2NwX2h5URswbuZsgH...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 2, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, god: nil, name: "Test User 123", sash_id: nil, level: 0, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2014-09-12 11:58:28", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil>
2.1.2 :012 >
```

Try out in your console.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think that it was wrong syntax as I use it elsewhere, though with different types.